# Why doesn't bootstrap nav-bar open on small screens?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This `nav-bar` works fine when the screen is larger than `640px`, but when the menu-button is displayed on small screens, clicking it does not show menu items. Here is the [site](http://www.bunkerhill.com/#/).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#BHC-Navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bunker Hill</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="BHC-Navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> Clients</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#about" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> About</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Contact</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the `bootstrap.min.js` so you need to add something like this:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

You need to add jQuery library before loading this js file.

Comment: Thanks. It was missing, but I added it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to add jQuery library before loading this js file. I'm not sure when using angular but give it a try

Comment: That did it. I didn't realize bootstrap was dependent on jquery.

Comment: Yup it does depends on it

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're calling bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js anywhere. Call that script and you should be good to go.

Comment: I added a reference to it, but it still doesn't work.